# Why using Yaml to add disqus to my hackmd page isn't working?

Tags: yaml, disqus, messageboard, hackmd

Disqus shortname won't work on hackmd

I have inserted the yaml as instructed to the top of my hackmd page which is open to the public

The code:

```
---
disqus: myDisqusShortName
---
```

however, the message board just is not showing.

Answer (score 1):

There are some tutorials on the web asked if the user entered the correct shortcode. It may be one of the parameters has to be checked first.

Also, note that the YAML tag has to be entered at the very first line of the note.

I also found that HackMD cannot use Disqus with multiple hyphens (-). If you found the Disqus loads in an infinite loop or prompt "We were unable to load Disqus.", try to generate a shortcode without any hyphen and update the YAML tag again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I tried multiple tutorials, however, the page remains the same, even without Disqus showing that it cannot be loaded.

Comment: I have made a sample on HackMD, you may wish to have a look at my sample

https://hackmd.io/@byronwai/rkyzPwjwY

Comment: @ByronWai Is this sample still available? How can I obtain the access to it? It will be great to have a look in order to solve this long-pending puzzle.

Comment: @lili I have re-activate the sample and set the correct permission

you may wish to check if your hackmd is published or not